# How to format the currency in HTML5 with thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, thymeleaf, currency-formatting

I am stuck with formatting the currency in HTML 5. I have application where I have to format the currency. I have below code snippet

```
 <td class="right"><span th:inline="text">$ [[${abc.value}]]</span></td>
```

Where from DAO abc I am reading the currency value, it should be formatted. 
Currently printing   $ 1200000.0 it should print $ 1,200,000.0 .0

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can use the `#numbers` utility object, which methods you can see here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.15/org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html

For example:

```
<span th:inline="text">$ [[${#numbers.formatDecimal(abc.value, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}]]</span>
```

Nevertheless, you can also do this without inlining (which is the thymeleaf recommended way):

```
<td>$ <span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(abc.value, 0, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}">10.00</span></td>
```

Comment: Is there any possibility to remove the zero's `10.00`, hmm It will be more clean to only show the decimals when there are any, but if we have a decimal number so it get rounded to `435.89`??

Comment: I had the same question.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066661/remove-trailing-zeros-on-currency

Answer (score 29):

I recommend to use the **DEFAULT** value (= based on locale) in case your application has to deal with different languages :

```
${#numbers.formatDecimal(abc.value, 1, 'DEFAULT', 2, 'DEFAULT')}
```

From [Thymeleaf doc](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#numbers) (more precisely [NumberPointType](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.1.4.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/util/NumberPointType.html)) :

```
/* 
 * Set minimum integer digits and thousands separator: 
 * 'POINT', 'COMMA', 'NONE' or 'DEFAULT' (by locale).
 * Also works with arrays, lists or sets
 */
${#numbers.formatInteger(num,3,'POINT')}
${#numbers.arrayFormatInteger(numArray,3,'POINT')}
${#numbers.listFormatInteger(numList,3,'POINT')}
${#numbers.setFormatInteger(numSet,3,'POINT')}

/*
 * Set minimum integer digits and (exact) decimal digits, and also decimal separator.
 * Also works with arrays, lists or sets
 */
${#numbers.formatDecimal(num,3,2,'COMMA')}
${#numbers.arrayFormatDecimal(numArray,3,2,'COMMA')}
${#numbers.listFormatDecimal(numList,3,2,'COMMA')}
${#numbers.setFormatDecimal(numSet,3,2,'COMMA')}
```

Comment: If value is below `1`, e.g. `0.55`, then result of this expression is `.55`. I recommend setting minimum integer digits to `1`: `${#numbers.formatDecimal(abc.value, 1, 'DEFAULT', 2, 'DEFAULT')}`. Then result is `0.55`.

Answer (score 14):

You can now more simply call the `formatCurrency` method in the `numbers` utility:

`#numbers.formatCurrency(abc.value)`

This will remove the need for a currency symbol as well.

Example:
`<span th:remove="tag" th:text="${#numbers.formatCurrency(abc.value)}">$100</span>`

Comment: This method is nowhere to be found in Thymeleaf's API.

Comment: https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.9.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/expression/Numbers.html#formatCurrency-java.lang.Number-  And you can click the Upvote to undo your vote.

Comment: what if I need to format a different currency? Euro, pound, etc.

Comment: That would be outside the scope of this question, of course, since OP is looking purely at showing dollars (current locale) and there is no requirement for multiple currencies.  But there is an open issue on GitHub for exactly this: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/604.  To describe the external link, the longer form using `formatDecimal` would be used, but there could be some interest in a `formatCurrency(number, locale)` method.

Answer (score 0):

You'd inline using Thymeleaf's numbers utility object as follows:

```
<span>[[${#numbers.formatCurrency(abc.value)}]]</span>
```

In the view, it'll even prepend the dollar sign ($) for you.

Comment: You'll lose the default text between the span tags with inlining.  Open the page directly in a browser (without the container/server) and you'll see the difference.  This is a major strength of Thymeleaf that you'd be losing.

Comment: Agreed. The original post used inlining and my suggestion was biased that-a-ways.