# How to Display Currency Symbols in Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jhipster

**I am preparing Product Quotation so I want to display Currency symbol in my Thymeleaf Template**

I am using unicode value(HEX) for currency symbol from this website https://www.ip2currency.com/currency-symbol

I have written `<p th:utext="${currencySymbol}"/>` in my HTML page to display currency symbol but it is not working, here **currencySymbol** is my thymeleaf variable and it's value is `&#x20b9;` and I am using Spring Boot

Please Help me, How to dispay currency symbol in thymeleaf template using Unicode

Comment: You can see my (incorrectly) downvoted answer as a workaround if you don't want to use the symbols from that website: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160304/how-to-format-the-currency-in-html5-with-thymeleaf

Comment: Otherwise, you may need to set the `contentType` on the `ThymeleafViewResolver` to UTF-8

Comment: Unicode value came from Database, different currency will have different Unicode value So I need to display it. 
Please Can you tell me that how and where (In which file)  I have to set ThymeleafViewResolver ?

Comment: You tagged your question with iText but I don't see anything in your question about PDF? Only about HTML? Please clarify.

Comment: from the generated Thymeleaf template I am creating PDF file of it using  IText

Comment: Then the current question is not iText related. At the moment you are still generating the HTML, and that's where the problem is.

Comment: Something like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397203/utf8-charset-with-thymeleaf.  There would be similar code for Java config (shown in the external link on that answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use like this

`<span th:utext="${'&#36;'+'&nbsp;'}" ></span></b><span th:text="${p.price}"></span>`
it is written inside a span tag
one span for currency(html of dollar) and another span tag fro dsplaying price from db