# Remove trailing zeros on currency

Tags: thymeleaf

In Thymeleaf, is there any way to print currencies without trailing zeroes if zeroes exist?

For example:

$49.20 --> $49.20

and

$49.00 --> $49

What I would imagine is something like: `#numbers.formatCurrency(abc.value, removeTrailingZeros)`

Comment: Are you using Spring?

Comment: Yes, Spring MVC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
$<span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(value, 0, T(Math).round(value) == value ? 0 : 2)}" />
```

(I'd probably prefer adding a getter for this, or some kind of utility method.)

--

How about this solution, if you still only want to use `formatCurrency`:

```
${#strings.replace(#numbers.formatCurrency(abc.value), '.00', '')}
```

Comment: nice, but you'd lose the currency symbol

Comment: @bphilipnyc second option?

Comment: The second option would do it!

Comment: This logic will break for global markets. Not every country uses a decimal dot for fraction digits separation. For ex: The USA amount of `$49.50`, is displayed as `€49,50` in France.

Answer (score 1):

With this complicated formatting when you want to preserve zeroes in some cases, remove them in others and show $$ instead of $ - maybe it makes sense to make your custom formatter bean and call the methods like

```
${@myFormatterBean.customFormat(abc.value)}
```

You will be able to control all the formatting.

Comment: I'd rather not mess with currency symbols