# Make a number comma separated in Thymleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

Hi currently i have code which convert a number into two decimal places in Thymleaf.

```
<h6 class = "font-weight-bold" 
 th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal((purchase.itemPrice * purchase.count),1,2,'POINT')}">
```

I want to make this number also comma separated.How can i do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use comma as thousand separator or as decimal separator? If thousand separator, that should work according to https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-utility-methods-for-numbers

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160304/how-to-format-the-currency-in-html5-with-thymeleaf/48617538#48617538

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format the currency in HTML5 with thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14160304/how-to-format-the-currency-in-html5-with-thymeleaf)